# Per-pixel logic in Photoshop

Tags: image-processing, photoshop, gimp

I have 2 images.

[image]
[image]

I need to create a 3rd image, based on this logic:

**If the pixel in image 1 and 2 is identical, the pixel in image 3 should be transparent.**

**If the pixel is different between image 1 and 2, use the pixel from image 1.**

Photoshop blend modes don't seem to be the right direction. Are there any good 3rd party or scripting tools for this kind of operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pending a more clever solution, with Gimp:

- Stack the images as layers
- Fill the background of both images with white (bucket fill the whole layer in `Behind` mode)
- Set top to `Difference` mode and create a layer with the result (`Layer > New from visible`)
- Threshold the layer/ This is where you discover that your images are far from identical outside of the spear... (*). In an ideal world, you would threshold at "1" but here you have way too much noise, "20" seems a bare minimum)
- Copy one of the RGB channels to a new channel
- Make a copy of Image 1, and add a layer mask, initializing to the channel you copied.

[image]

(*) Here is the alpha channel of Image1: plenty of random not-so-transparent dots:

[image]

And Image2 is similar, with other random dots:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you're correct, it seems as if a post-processing image editor is the wrong way to go about finding a pixel-perfect solution. I'll play around in Gimp some more. Thanks!